# Can setEnabled() Function can be overidden,if so how?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

```
public class AppaSwitch extends AppCompatImageButton implements View.OnClickListener {

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

}
```

Like the above `code` is there a way to override `setEnabled()` function in `android`.The below is an example but I see no method like this

```
public class AppaSwitch extends AppCompatImageButton implements View.OnEnabled {

     @Override
        public void OnEnabled(View v) {

        }

    }
```

Or is there any alternate way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setEnabled() is the method of View class and `AppCompatImageButton` already extends `View` Class, so you can directly override as done here:

```
public class AppaSwitch extends AppCompatImageButton {
    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        //your piece of code

        //if you want to remove below line to remove the function of super class.
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the `View` class to be able to override `setEnabled`, and then define your own interface to implement such a `onEnabled` callback method.

However, I think you should use a `Switch` or other `CompoundButton`  to determine `onCheckChanged`.

Or you can use the regular click listener plus some `EventBus` library to notify view enablement

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom switch like below,

```
 public class AppCustomSwitch extends AppCompatImageButton {
    private OnEnabledListener listener;

    public AppCustomSwitch(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AppCustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AppCustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        if(enabled){
            listener.OnEnabled(this);
        }
    }

    public void setOnEnabledListener(OnEnabledListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnEnabledListener{
        public void OnEnabled(View v);
    }
}
```

And make your activity/fragment to implement `AppCustomSwitch.OnEnabledListener`

```
    public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppCustomSwitch.OnEnabledListener{

    private AppCustomSwitch customSwitch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        customSwitch = findViewById(R.id.custom_switch);
        customSwitch.setOnEnabledListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnEnabled(View v) {
        // your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no such thing as a OnEnabledListener.

Comment: I have defined OnEnabledListener in the AppCustomSwitch class. Its custom interface.

Answer (score -1):

You can not `seEnabled();` method because it's a setter method and not an `interface` method

Comment: unless a setter is final, it can be overriden